# WPF Window/Frame/Page

Tags: wpf, xaml, window

I have a Window which holds a Grid containing: a Label and a Frame. The Frame holds a Page. The Page has a Button and a Label.

Both Labels (on Window and Page) are bound to the same string property, which initially works correctly.

The Button (on the page) changes the string property, which I expect to change both the Label on the Window and the Label on the Page.

The problem is that it only changes the Label on the Page and not the Label on the Window. Is there a way to have a button on a page change an element in it's parent window? Also, if there is an explanation of why this is happening I would appreciate it.

[image: ViewModel with Output Screen Shots]

Window Xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding SourceTitleHeader, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Foreground="Red">
        </Label>
    </Grid>

    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="\Views\Page1.xaml">

    </Frame>

</Grid>
```

Page Xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <Label Content="{Binding SourceTitleHeader, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="0 0 0 20">

    </Label>

    <Button Content="ChangeLabel" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Command="{Binding Refresh_Screen_Command}">

    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you set DataContext.

Comment: It seems both window and frame are bound to two different object and not same one.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I added my Xaml DataContext for both the Window and Page. If I understand you correctly, I believe they are bound to the same object since they initially both hold "Hello World".

Comment: Not really, they are bound to two different object as you can see from the code wpf will create 2 different MainWindowViewModel objects; one for Window and another for page.

Comment: Ohhhh. That makes sense. How does one overcome that? I tried removing DataContext from the page, but that didn't work.

Comment: It'll not because the way WPF works. Any element inside frame cannot access DataContext/property from outside of frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different objects used for `DataContext` of window and page, make sure you are using same object.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding SourceTitleHeader, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Foreground="Red">
        </Label>
    </Grid>

    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Frame.Content>
            <local:Page1 DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" />
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>

</Grid>
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. I had to change the two "local:" to "viewmodel:" and "view:" which  is where my viewmodel and view are. I will research this, but is it easy to explain how adding the ResourceDictionary fixed things?

Comment: Yup, so basically Frame in wpf is a boundary between controls inside and outside frame. Generally, child control can access properties from `DataContext `of parent which is not case for the control under `Frame`. Adding you model as a static resource allows you to access it within the window that is why in the code I posted, I was able to successfully set DataContext for window and frame to same object.

Comment: awesome. Thanks!